# set checked status on input type checkbox in ngFor Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I have an angular 2 application, where i use a ngFor to handle an bunch of checkboxes. when i initialize this component i need to set the state of the checkbox based on weather an id excists in an array

```
<div *ngFor="let option of listOptionResponse.options" class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            {{option.headline}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 ">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control"  (change)="ServiceAddOrRemove($event, option.id)" name="choose">
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the component i have an array and if the options.id exists in this array i wanna set it to true.

I cannot think of a good way to do this, and i have been looking for some sort of init event to use, bu without luck.
(this has nothing to do whith the excisting (change) event)

I hope you can help, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just bind to `checked` like

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control"  (change)="ServiceAddOrRemove($event, option.id)" name="choose"  
    [checked]="ids.indexOf(option.id) != -1">
```

Comment: it needs the id to be present in an array of the scope `[checked] = "ids.indexOf(option.id) != -1"`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="option.id" class="form-control"  (change)="ServiceAddOrRemove($event, option.id)" name="choose">
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!